# how to render only a certain set of data in a sub-array with VueJS

Tags: json, vue.js, v-for, computed-properties

I have this problem where i have a set of JSON format files that look like this :

```
{ 
"_id" : "name_id", 
"apkMode" : "SCROLL", 
"date" : "2022-04-25", 
"timestamp" : NumberLong(16551858512), 
"user" : "name", 
"interactions" : [
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650912989260), 
        "subject" : "ROBOT", 
        "type" : "selfEvaluationQuestion", 
        "text" : "test selfEvaluationQuestion"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913013738), 
        "subject" : "HUMAN", 
        "type" : "selfEvaluationAnswer", 
        "text" : "test selfEvaluationAnswer"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913022948), 
        "subject" : "ROBOT", 
        "type" : "newsCore", 
        "text" : "test newsCore"
    },
```

and so on.
each users have a varying number of interactions arrays and they can all contain a different type of data.
In a VueJS table, i need to cycle in every array and if the type of data is correct , display it in this cell. however, I am unable to find a working solution. I tried to use v-for with a v-if (I know it is not optimal but this just does not work

```
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p v-if="(sessions.interactions[index].type = 'newsCore')">
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
```

but this does not show anything, and I have the same result with computed properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Observations :***

- You are doing iteration directly on `interactions` array which is not correct as it should be accessed via `userObj.interactions`.

  ```
  v-for="(interaction, index) in userObj.interactions"
  ```
- Instead of comparison operator, You are using assignment operator inside `v-if` which is also not correct. It should be **:**

  ```
  v-if="interaction.type === 'newsCore'"
  ```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userObj: { 
      "_id" : "name_id", 
      "apkMode" : "SCROLL", 
      "date" : "2022-04-25", 
      "timestamp" : '16551858512', 
      "user" : "name", 
      "interactions" : [
        {
          "interactionTimestamp" : '1650912989260', 
          "subject" : "ROBOT", 
          "type" : "selfEvaluationQuestion", 
          "text" : "test selfEvaluationQuestion"
        }, 
        {
          "interactionTimestamp" : '1650913013738', 
          "subject" : "HUMAN", 
          "type" : "selfEvaluationAnswer", 
          "text" : "test selfEvaluationAnswer"
        }, 
        {
          "interactionTimestamp" : '1650913022948', 
          "subject" : "ROBOT", 
          "type" : "newsCore", 
          "text" : "test newsCore"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Interaction Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span
              v-for="(interaction, index) in userObj.interactions"
              :key="index"
              >
          <p v-if="interaction.type === 'newsCore'">
            {{ interaction.text }}
          </p>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much. i forgot about the === to compare after modifying almost everything, and it just never got to me to use "in userObj.interactions". Also thank you for taking the time to rewrite my code, you really helped me.

Comment: @wayfarer85 Kindly do accept the answer if it helps you. So that it will helpful for other fellow developers as well.